# Mailx setup in Linux - not sure if error message means configuration error

Tags: linux, mailx

I have a Raspberry Pi that periodically sends email updates of the current IP address whenever it changes.  I had it working perfectly a couple of weeks ago, and recently it is no longer sending emails properly.  As far as I know I haven't changed any of the configuration files for the setup, so I cannot figure out why it no longer works.  I looked in the mail logs and found this error

```
----- Transcript of session follows -----
554 5.0.0 MX list for emc.com. points back to mailhub.lss.emc.com
554 5.3.5 Local configuration error
550 5.1.1 password... User unknown
```

I know this says local configuration error, but everywhere I looked the user/password combination looks correct.  What is the MX list? Thanks!

Comment: In the error from the server `mailhub.lss.emc.com`, when it says "local" it means "local to `mailhub.lss.emc.com`". The SMTP server and the DNS are having a disagreement about who's responsible for handling `emc.com`'s mail. It's not a problem with the sender.

Comment: Got it. So do I just need to wait it out then?